# How to move/migrate a web-site from "my-site " to another location in share point?

Tags: sharepoint

How to move/migrate a web-site from "my-site " to another location in share point ?
is it possible to do that,I'm new to share point, help me out !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not simply move a site in SharePoint. One work around is to use a site and save it as a template. When you create a template you have an option to save the content as part of the template. Then create the site in the new location with that template.

This would only be viable for a couple sites. IF you are planing to move all sites in a site collection you can accomplish that with a backup of the site collection and then restore it in a different location.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Metalogix Migration Manager to move subsites within a site-collection.
http://www.metalogix.com/products/migration-manager-for-sharepoint/SharePoint-Upgrade.aspx

While content of the sites can be moved, you might still have to customize layouts, set permissions (because they are very likely to get skewed, for some reason). I just you copy the site to another location, and then customize as required, before removing the original site.

Comment: Suggesting to purchase a tool to do the job is not solving the problem. You may as well tell him to go hire a developer to do it for him.